# Best way to back up Azure Blob Storage

Tags: backup, azure-blob-storage

I would like to use Azure Blobs to store user uploaded images for a website. Upon upload the images are resized and put into folders for thumbnails, large pics and originals. These can be easily referenced from the website, so the solution works pretty well.

The problem is the backup. I understand that Azure has three copies of every blob to protect against hardware failure. If an authenticated user deletes the blob, MS will faithfully delete all three copies, which is a problem.

I couldn't find an easy way to regularly back up and restore a blob container to a point in time. Is there such a solution offered in the azure marketplace that anyone knows of? Maybe this would be better on ServerFault as I'm looking for a canned solution, but the MS link sent me over to Stack Overflow so I'm giving it a shot here.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use blob snapshots. Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691971.aspx